# Enabling SSH remotely on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssh, putty

Suppose I have a server that has Ubuntu 18.04 installed. If I want to enable ssh on it, do I have to physically be in the server room to do it? Or can I do it remotely? I have a Windows laptop and just downloaded PuTTY. For the host name would I put the ip address of the nameserver? So if it is:

```
                               nameserver 128.0.0.54
```

is that the ip address I would enter into PuTTY?

**Edit**   Actually would it be the ip from `sudo lshw -C network`?

Comment: What are you asking?  How are you currently interacting with your server?

Comment: @NmathL I physically go into the server room and access it there. I want to access it remotely.

Comment: A proper install of Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Core already has an ssh server installed (enabled). An install of Ubuntu Desktop does not. A frankensystem built up from a minimal image or Ubuntu Base also does not. There are many excellent tutorials on how to use ssh already -- have you looked at any of those?

Comment: @user535733: Basically I want to use Putty on my windows laptop to access the server. That should be possible right/

Comment: Name server is the server the resolves names, also called DNS, it’s not the IP of your server. Type ifconfig on your Ubuntu to get its IP address. Then put that in Putty to connect to it.

Comment: Suppose you want to call my home. My home does not have a phone. Can you install a phone in my home without coming to my home?

Answer (score 1):

SSH has a server part and client part. Your Ubuntu server should be having SSH server installed already and configured for you to be able to connect remotely using Putty (SSH client here).

To install SSH server, if it is not already installed, you have to be at the physical location of the server to login and install the needed packages.

I don't wish to enlist other tougher ways to get into the machine without SSH as it will be out of scope of the question asked.